# Eigen C++ Sparse Matrix elementwise product and divide

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I am trying to convert some methods implemented in Eigen C++ dense matrix class (`MatrixXd` from `<Eigen/Dense>`) to methods with Eigen C++ sparse matrix (like `SparseMatrix<double>` from `<Eigen/Sparse>`).

Many methods can be directly transformed by simply chance `MatrixXd` to `SparseMatrix<double>`. However, some methods cannot be.

One problem I met is to convert the following elementwise dividend into sparse matrix method:

```
(beta.array() / beta.cwiseAbs().array()).sum()
```

Originally, `beta` is declared as `MatrixXd beta`. Now, if I declare `beta` as `SparseMatrix<double> beta`, there is no more corresponding `array()` method to allow me to do the above.

How should I still perform element-wise operations with sparse matrix?

Is there any efficient way that I can convert dense matrix to sparse matrix and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported because rigorously you would compute 0/0 for any explicit zeros. You can workaround if the matrix is in compress mode, to be sure call:

```
beta.makeCompressed();
```

then map the nonzeros as a dense array:

```
Map<ArrayXd> a(beta.valuePtr(), beta.nonZeros();
(a / a.abs()).sum;
```

Comment: Is there a way turn a sparse matrix back to dense matrix?

Comment: Use Matrix constructor: MatrixXd dense(beta);

Comment: Why not multiplication, though?